# What to do about the "Member of the board asks for admin access" Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Member of the board asks for admin access and wants non-compliant device on the network](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/112683/member-of-the-board-asks-for-admin-access-and-wants-non-compliant-device-on-the?noredirect=1#comment350561_112683)
is a current hot-network question.

However, the question has a key problem, in that the titular "Member of the Board",
is not a member of the board in the usual sense.

From the comments:

> **erickson:**  Are you talking about a member of your company's board of directors? Is this person an inside director who has an additional position in the company? It seems like they should be working through the appropriate officer.
>   **MKZ (OP):** @erickson company is rather small. It has several board members and she is our main supervisor.
>   **LyndonWhite:** I'm not sure you are using the term board-member in the fashion I am used to it being used. As I understand it a board-member normally represents the share-holders of the company. The company executives report to the board, but beyond that they don't normally interact with the company's staff.
>   **MKZ (OP):** @LyndonWhite I'm sorry. I meant the daily staff. Highest rank that is daily at the company.

So while I am not sure what position the titular person holds,
it is not that of member of the board of directors.

Several of the current answers work on the assumption that the person is an actual member of the board.
If the question is updated to have the true position those will be invalidated.
But mostly only in a minor way.

Comment: I don't think that detail matters.  If someone makes a request that is not normal and they out-rank you, what would you change in the answers?  The over riding theme is cover your assets.  CYA.

Comment: That is why it is perhaps a good practice to quote the parts of the Question that you are addressing... so in case things change your answer does not end up hanging and prone to DV from confused users.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it alone.  the question is still one that many people will run into and the answers are useful.  SE tends to go by the [Death of the Author](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor) model, so what has suddenly come up in comments doesn't change the merit of the question.

Comment: Agreed, the Questions and answers still have value regardless of the details.